# How to close time input after picking the time?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<label class="form-label" for="taskTime">Enter Finish Time:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="time" id="taskTime" required />
```

After choosing the time the time picker remains open, how close it after choosing the time?

Comment: Do you want it to close when the user selects the AM/PM? Or the hour? How does it know that you're done picking the time?

Comment: Why do you have `for="time"` but no element with `id="time"`? Why not simply nest the `<input>` inside the `<label>` to avoid tracking `for` and `id` attributes?

Comment: @SebastianSimon i forget to change the id of the `for` , how i nest the `<input>` inside of the `<label>`?

Comment: @RichardHenage it doesnt have a AM/PM it opens a 24 Hour clock, i want it close after the user clicks on the time

Comment: @ilanMoroz maybe we are seeing different things. I am seeing this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time/edge_time.png

Comment: The displayed format indeed depends on your [operating system locale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/time#chrome_and_opera)

Comment: @RichardHenage as Reyno has put it, it's different on different devices, this is true for almost all input elements. The problem now is what does the time element look like for the OP. Also, what browser and OS is he on?

Comment: @RichardHenage https://postimg.cc/TLYfhYBk

Comment: @ilanMoroz Okay. So if you click on 22, and then 10, you want the input to automatically close?

Comment: @RichardHenage yes exactly

Comment: @ilanMoroz check my answer below, will it work for you?

Comment: @ahmedmoeed it will be better if it will close after 2 clicks.

Comment: Please explain briefly what you mean 2 click, how?

Answer (score 0):

you can add **`HTMLElement.blur()`** method on input event listener to remove the focus on input field.

```js
let taskTime = document.querySelector('#taskTime');
taskTime.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  taskTime.blur();
});
```

```html
<label class="form-label" for="taskTime">Enter Finish Time:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="time" id="taskTime" required />
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all the date picker will be different with respect to the OS and Browser. Closing the time picker is not a good practise.

This Will solve the problem partially

```js
let timePicker = document.getElementById("taskTime")

timePicker.addEventListener('input', updateValue);

function updateValue() {
  timePicker.type = 'text';
  timePicker.type = 'time';
}
```

```html
<label class="form-label" for="time">Enter Finish Time:</label>
<input class="form-control" type="time" id="taskTime" required />
```

Comment: big clap, you are the man.